# how to make it easier to list several variables from a database depending on the amount of data

Tags: javascript, discord.js

how to make it easier to list several variables from a database depending on the amount of data.
I will be adding even more data so simplification is needed
I currently have something like that, but there is a way to simplify it:

```
              if(rows.length >= 5) {
                    const embed = new RichEmbed()
                    .setColor(process.env.KOLOR)
                    .setThumbnail(message.member.displayAvatarURL)
                    .setFooter(message.member.displayName, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setDescription(`#${rows[0].nr} Typ: ${rows[0].rodzaj} Powód: ${rows[0].powod}\n
                    #${rows[1].nr} Typ: ${rows[1].rodzaj} Powód: ${rows[1].powod}\n
                    #${rows[2].nr} Typ: ${rows[2].rodzaj} Powód: ${rows[2].powod}\n
                    #${rows[3].nr} Typ: ${rows[3].rodzaj} Powód: ${rows[3].powod}\n
                    #${rows[4].nr} Typ: ${rows[4].rodzaj} Powód: ${rows[4].powod}`);
                    message.channel.send(embed);
                }
                if(rows.length === 4) {
                    const embed = new RichEmbed()
                    .setColor(process.env.KOLOR)
                    .setThumbnail(message.member.displayAvatarURL)
                    .setFooter(message.member.displayName, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setDescription(`#${rows[0].nr} Typ: ${rows[0].rodzaj} Powód: ${rows[0].powod}\n
                    #${rows[1].nr} Typ: ${rows[1].rodzaj} Powód: ${rows[1].powod}\n
                    #${rows[2].nr} Typ: ${rows[2].rodzaj} Powód: ${rows[2].powod}\n
                    #${rows[3].nr} Typ: ${rows[3].rodzaj} Powód: ${rows[3].powod}`);
                    message.channel.send(embed);
                }
                if(rows.length === 3) {
                    const embed = new RichEmbed()
                    .setColor(process.env.KOLOR)
                    .setThumbnail(message.member.displayAvatarURL)
                    .setFooter(message.member.displayName, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setDescription(`#${rows[0].nr} Typ: ${rows[0].rodzaj} Powód: ${rows[0].powod}\n
                    #${rows[1].nr} Typ: ${rows[1].rodzaj} Powód: ${rows[1].powod}\n
                    #${rows[2].nr} Typ: ${rows[2].rodzaj} Powód: ${rows[2].powod}`);
                    message.channel.send(embed);
                }
                if(rows.length === 2) {
                    const embed = new RichEmbed()
                    .setColor(process.env.KOLOR)
                    .setThumbnail(message.member.displayAvatarURL)
                    .setFooter(message.member.displayName, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setDescription(`#${rows[0].nr} Typ: ${rows[0].rodzaj} Powód: ${rows[0].powod}\n
                    #${rows[1].nr} Typ: ${rows[1].rodzaj} Powód: ${rows[1].powod}`);
                    message.channel.send(embed);
                }
                if(rows.length === 1) {
                    const embed = new RichEmbed()
                    .setColor(process.env.KOLOR)
                    .setThumbnail(message.member.displayAvatarURL)
                    .setFooter(message.member.displayName, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setDescription(`#${rows[0].nr} Typ: ${rows[0].rodzaj} Powód: ${rows[0].powod}`);
                    message.channel.send(embed);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that with reduce inside your backticks:

```
const embed = new RichEmbed()
                .setColor(process.env.KOLOR)
                .setThumbnail(message.member.displayAvatarURL)
                .setFooter(message.member.displayName, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setDescription(rows.reduce((acc, cur) => `${acc}\n#${cur.nr} Typ: ${cur.rodzaj} Powód: ${cur.powod}`, '')
                message.channel.send(embed);
```

You can read more about array.reduce() [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)